# Minecraft Bedrock (Hive Server) Skywars Kits "Void Warp" Ability

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Skywars Kits has many kits, and I selected the Void Walker. One of its abilities is the "Void Warp", giving you an extra chance after you fall into the void. May I ask how many lives do you spawn with after falling into the void? Because when I was battling a player, I was knocked into the void, warped out, then immediatly died from a (single) hit from the same player.

Comment: How many hearts, you mean, right? How *much* life, rather?

Comment: I'd imagine it doesn't actually restore any health, and instead you just get teleported back with your current health. You probably died in one hit because you were one hit from death before being knocked off.

Comment: @Corsaka, instead, you could put that in question form and earn points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely no health is restored by the "Void Warp" ability - instead, it just teleports you back to where you were knocked off the map. Your health was probably low enough for you to be killed in one hit, and since you were teleported back to that location, the player was still there.